Azure pipeline CI: No profiles for 'com.my.app' were found
I am trying to use azure pipeline for CI/CD, but can't build my app. I set automatic code signing in Xcode. Also I uploaded all needed secure files both certificate and provisioning profiles.
pool: vmImage: 'macos-13'
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'development_cert.p12'
    certPwd: $(cert_password)

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'Developer_Profile.mobileprovision'

While executing pipeline script I made sure that certificate and profile exist via commands:
security find-identity -p codesigning -v
ls -lGa ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/

But the build script failed:
- script: |
    set -e
    xcodebuild build \
              -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
              -scheme 'MyApp (QA)' \
              -configuration 'Release (QA)' \
              -destination 'generic/platform=iOS'
  displayName: 'Xcode Build'

Error: MyApp.xcodeproj: error: No profiles for 'com.my.app' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.my.app'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'MyTarget' from project 'MyApp')
So, the question is why azure pipeline can't grab uploaded profile and how to fix that?
The same script worked correctly in my local Mac.
When I passed the same certificate and profile as parameters
CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual \
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='iPhone Distribution: My App Inc. (XXYYYYZZZZ)' \
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="My Developer Profile" \

the script could recognize the profile. (But it failed due to another reason)

After the InstallAppleCertificate@2 and InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1 tasks, you can use the built-in Xcode@5 task to run the Xcode build step.
steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'development_cert.p12'
    certPwd: '$(cert_password)'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'Developer_Profile.mobileprovision'

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    configuration: 'Release (QA)'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'MyApp (QA)'
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    destinationPlatformOption: 'iOS'

The variables APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY and APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID are automatically set by the InstallAppleCertificate@2 and InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1 tasks so that the subsequent tasks can use the certificate and profile installed by them.
For more details, see "Sign your Apple iOS, macOS, tvOS, or watchOS app".

EDIT:
If your build needs multiple provisioning profiles, you can try like as below:

Add an InstallAppleCertificate@2 task to install your P12 signing certificate from Secure Files.

Add multiple InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1 task, each one installs a required provisioning profile from Secure Files.

Use the Xcode@5 task with below configurations.
steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'development_cert.p12'
    certPwd: '$(cert_password)'

# Add multiple to install all the required provisioning profiles.
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  . . .

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    configuration: 'Release (QA)'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'MyApp (QA)'
    signingOption: default
    destinationPlatformOption: 'iOS'




EDIT_2:
Currently, the Xcode@5 task is using Xcode 13 by default. On this task, you can use the option xcodeVersion to specified a different version of Xcode. for example, you can specify the version to be same as that on your local machine that can build the same app without error code 65.
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    configuration: 'Release (QA)'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'MyApp (QA)'
    xcodeVersion: 8
    signingOption: default
    destinationPlatformOption: 'iOS'

The listed versions of Xcdoe are 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and 13.
If none of above versions is the one you want, you can add script task before the Xcode@5 task to install the specified version. And then provide the path (/Applications/Xcode_{version_number}.app/Contents/Developer) on the Xcode@5 task.
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    configuration: 'Release (QA)'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'MyApp (QA)'
    xcodeVersion: specifyPath
    xcodeDeveloperDir: path/to/xcode
    signingOption: default
    destinationPlatformOption: 'iOS'


EDIT_3:
Based on the latest README of Microsoft-hosted macOS-13 agent:
The Xcode 8 is not a pre-installed version on the agent macOS-13. If you want to use it, as mentioned above, you need to install it and set the environment variable "XCODE_8_DEVELOPER_DIR" with the installation path of Xcode 8 (/Applications/Xcode_8.x.x.app/Contents/Developer). The '8.x.x' is the detailed version of Xcode 8.
You also can see the valid SDKs for iOS installed on macOS-13 agent. You can set one of them as the value of the pipeline variable "$(SDK)".


I can't use Xcode@5 task because my app has widget, and I have to pass 2 provisioning profiles. I can't use wildcard App ID because the app requires some capabilities that can't be set if I choose wildcard App ID.
I simplify description to clearly identify root problem

@RomanMarkov, If you need to use the script task to run the "xcodebuild build" command, you also can use the variables to pass the certificate and profile as parameters to the command with Manual option. Just like you mentioned above.

@BrightRanMSFT via parameters I can pass only one provisioning profile. At least based on what I've read.

@RomanMarkov, I have provided more suggestions in my answer above. See EDIT.

@BrightRanMSFT I got error with 65 code##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
Under the hood comand:
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release (QA) -workspace /Users/runner/work/1/s/MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp (QA) build | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/xcpretty -r junit --no-color
Trying to modify the xcodebuild command

When I run the command above I again got error about missing needed provisioning profile.

@RomanMarkov, The Xcode@5 task is using Xcode 13 by default. Try to use a older version of Xcode. For more details, see EDIT_2 in my above answer.

@BrightRanMSFT Sorry, I forgot to set xcodeVersion: 8 for Xcode@5 task, but when I set I got error##[error]Error: Unable to resolve the developer path for Xcode 8. Set the XCODE_8_DEVELOPER_DIRenvironment variable on the agent machine, or setXcode versiontoDefaultorSpecify path.
When I deleted this option I got error:
xcodebuild: error: SDK "$(SDK)" cannot be located. ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 64
When I added option 'sdk: 'iphoneos'' I got error:
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

@BrightRanMSFT I need Xcode 15 because we use #Preview macro. That's why I set pool: vmImage: 'macos-13' because by default it uses Xcode 15

@BrightRanMSFT do you think in older Xcode version xcodebuild can find profiles?

@RomanMarkov, I think the older Xcode versions also can have the ability to get the profiles, as it is not new ability only on the new versions. For the two errors you mentioned above, see EDIT_3 in my answer.
